# Странное поведение события ItemCheck

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на CheckBox внутри CheckListBox должно срабатывать событие ExceptionsBox_ItemCheck:

```cs
private void ExceptionsBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  Exceptions.Clear();

  foreach (var item in ExceptionsBox.CheckedItems)
  {
    Exceptions.Add(item.ToString());
  }
}
```

Обычно событие срабатывает при нажатии на следующий элемент, как бы с "задержкой в шаг". Как сделать, чтобы событие срабатывало всегда по нажатию на CheckBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не задержка, это событие возникает до того как состояние поменяется.

Есть костыль, который я **не рекомендую** использовать, но он просто есть, можно отложить выполнение тела метода асинхронным способом:

1. меняете `void` на `async void`
2. в начало метода добавляете `await Task.Yield();`
3. остальной код метода оборачиваете в `try-catch`, чтобы не потерять контроль над возникающими исключениями и недопустить падения приложения

А **рекомендую** сделать что-то такое:

Допустим ни один чекбокс не помечен в изначальном состоянии, а коллекция пуста. Допустим, коллекция это `List<string>`.

Тогда получится как-то так.

```
private void ExceptionsBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var box = (CheckListBox)sender;
    var item = box.Items[e.Index].ToString();
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        Exceptions.Add(item);
    else
        Exceptions.Remove(item);
}
```